# syntax error near or at case - postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm having some difficulties with this sql query.

```
do $$

begin
with total_ticks as (
    select count(*) c from (
    select *  from eurusd_tick2 eurusd where date > 
        (SELECT date from eurusd_ohlc order by date desc limit 1) 
        order by date asc) totals),
        ticks_for_candles as(
        select * from eurusd_tick2 eurusd where date > 
        (SELECT date from eurusd_ohlc order by date desc limit 1) 
        order by date asc
        ), candles as(
            select max(date) as date,
       max(bid) filter (where mod(seqnum, 500) = 1) as open,
       max(bid) as high,
       min(bid) as low,
       max(bid) filter (where mod(seqnum, 500) = 500-1) as close,
       max(ask) filter (where mod(seqnum, 500) = 500-1) as ask

        from (
            select t.*, row_number() over (order by date) as seqnum
              from (select * from ticks_for_candles) t) as a

        group by floor((seqnum - 1) /500)
        having count(*) = 500
        )


case 500>(select * from total_ticks)
when true then

        (select * from candles)
    end;
end $$;
```

I'm getting `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "case"`. What I'm looking for is, if there are 500 or more rows in `total_ticks`, then the desired output is:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|          date            |    open   |   high   |    low  |   close  |    ask   |
|2020-05-01 20:39:27.603452|    1.0976 |  1.09766 | 1.09732 | 1.09762  |  1.09776 |
```

And all other candles/rows that applies. The desired rows came from `candles`.

How do I fix this error? What I'm doing wrong?

Additionally, all the `candles` thing I also have it as a function, that is `generate_tickcandles()`. How can I give the function the table `total_ticks`? I tried `generate_tickcandles((select * from total_ticks))`, but I get an error that says that the subquery must return only 1 column.

---

EDIT: There is no `select` after CTEs. I have tried to do:

```
select case 1000>(select * from total_ticks)
when true then

        (select * from candles)
    end;
end $$;
```

And I get this error:

```
ERROR:  subquery must return only one column
LINE 31:   (select * from candles)
           ^
QUERY:  with total_ticks as (
    select count(*) c from (
    select *  from eurusd_tick2 eurusd where date > 
        (SELECT date from eurusd_ohlc order by date desc limit 1) 
        order by date asc) totals),
        ticks_for_candles as(
        select * from eurusd_tick2 eurusd where date > 
        (SELECT date from eurusd_ohlc order by date desc limit 1) 
        order by date asc
        ), candles as(
       select max(date) as date,
       max(bid) filter (where mod(seqnum, 500) = 1) as open,
       max(bid) as high,
       min(bid) as low,
       max(bid) filter (where mod(seqnum, 500) = 500-1) as close,
       max(ask) filter (where mod(seqnum, 500) = 500-1) as ask

        from (
            select t.*, row_number() over (order by date) as seqnum
              from (select * from ticks_for_candles) t) as a

        group by floor((seqnum - 1) /500)
        having count(*) = 500
        )


select case 1000>(select * from total_ticks)
when true then

        (select * from candles)
    end
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 4 at SQL statement
SQL state: 42601
```

The desired output of this is nothing if the requirements are not met or something like this, if they are:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|          date            |    open   |   high   |    low  |   close  |    ask   |
|2020-05-01 20:39:27.603452|    1.0976 |  1.09766 | 1.09732 | 1.09762  |  1.09776 |
```

Comment: I don't even know what `500>(select * from total_ticks)` is supposed to mean, but I am expecting a `select` after the CTEs.

Comment: Hi @GordonLinoff, `(select * from total_ticks)` give the number of ticks that are in the table eurusd_ticks2 after the last registered date. The output is a number, like 100, 594 or 1156. So, what I'm trying to aim with `500>(select * from total_ticks)` is something like: "if there are more than 500 ticks, then give me the OHLC of those ticks".
If I do a plain `select 500>(select * from total_ticks)` the output is boolean, which in this particular case is false.

Comment: Unrelated to the problem, but why the `do` block? That can't return any result from the query.

Comment: Hi @a_horse_with_no_name, honestly I'm trying to do it in a variety of ways. I have looked into other forum's questions and documentation, but haven't had any success yet. I don't care if this is with or without `do`, but I guess its the correct way to go since I want to transform this into a trigger lately.

Answer (score 0):

Pardon me, I work with T Sql but it appears that the With clause usage is similar in postgres sql. I am unable to find the `select` statement after you move out of all your CTEs declarations.

```
) **<-- This closes your Candles CTE** no DQL or DML statement follows. Directly starts with 
case 500 >(
```

In reference to error being thrown by : `select case 1000>(select * from total_ticks)`  . What are you attempting to accomplish? Because, 1000 is an integer and you are checking if it is greater than all the columns from total_ticks???

Comment: That ) actually closes the `total_ticks` part of the with clause. The `total_ticks` gives me the number of ticks that are in the eurusd_tick2 table.